# Why does CuPy create a copy in system RAM before transferring to VRAM?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, cupy

I'm trying to understand why CuPy creates a copy of an array that is already loaded on RAM when I transfer the same array to the GPU.

```py
data = cupyx.empty_pinned(shape, np.uint16)
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    f.readinto1(data)
data = cupy.array(data, copy=False)
```

I'm tracking current RAM and VRAM usage using HWiNFO64. Lines 1-3 here allocate and fill the expected amount RAM, but at line 4, RAM usage doubles up at the same time as VRAM is allocated and filled.

Are `uint16` somehow not supported by GPUs (RTX 4090 in my case)?

Comment: I didn't mention it in my post, but it's the same behaviour if I initially load the data using NumPy's `fromfile` method.

Comment: If it's relevant to the question, you should add it to the post, not a comment.

Comment: Seems to be this bug: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/7821

Comment: Seems like you're right. My code can stay as is in the meantime, I guess

Comment: pinned memory is a limited commodity on a system-level. It's allocation is also pretty slow. I'd argue you should not use `empty_pinned` in that way until the bug is resolved or you find a workaround. Just activate notifications on that bug and leave a comment in the code linking to it

Comment: My use-case might require frequent RAM-VRAM two-way transfers. Wouldn't it be more beneficial to keep them in pinned memory here (after the bug is fixed)?

Comment: Yes, *after* they are fixed, *if* it is ever fixed. From reading the bugs, it sounds like the current state is by design and they want to introduce a new parameter such as `copy(…, async=true)`. So you would need to rewrite that code anyway. Might as well save yourself the costs of using pinned memory until then

Comment: Also, please @ my name when responding. [I don't get a notification otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)